# Mediante CSS indicar que un elemento tiene 'overflow' desbordamiento lateral

Tags: html5, css3

¿Cómo puedo mostrar mediante CSS que un elemento de bloque tiene desbordamiento lateral?

En mi caso tengo una tabla con scroll horizontal dentro de un `div`. Inicialmente según el tamaño de la ventana, que puede cambiar dinámicamente, puede que la tabla no se vea entera y deseo indicar que hay más contenido con un `+` o una flecha `->`.

He visto una solución con javascript:

```
function isOverflown(element) {
return element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight || element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth;
}
```

y otra solución sería disparando un evento cada vez que hubiera un `overflow` de un `div`.

¿Se puede hacer algo solo con CSS?

Comment: No creo que sea posible con **css**, espero estar equivocado y que otro miembro de la comunidad te ofrezca una solución, pero recuerda que **css** es solo para dar estilos a tu **html** y no para leer propiedades o características de un elemento. Lo más que podrías hacer es dar estilos a la barra de desplazamiento con [::scrollbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar) pero no es relevante

Comment: Ok, no se si a lo mejor hay algún truco en CSS que juegue con ocultaciones

Comment: Si las dimensiones de la tabla fueran fijas, podrías usar media query y mostrar u ocultar las flechas. Si las dimensiones de la tabla las pudieras poner en un atributo podrías intentar usar los select  con condición e CSS (div[valor=]). Pero creo que el camino más acertado es Javascript.

Comment: Una solución a mi problema sería que la barra de desplazamiento fuera siempre visible. Actualmente en los navegadores, sobre todo los navegadores móviles, esta barra es solo es visible cuando hago un desplazamiento.